# Is it possible to create a DOM node (and then appendChild it into some DOM element) from an existing SVG file?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, svg, dom

I would really appreciate if somebody helps me to solve the following problem.
There is a span-element inside of rendered DOM tree which contains some svg-element:

```
<...>
  <span>
    <svg>
      <path d="..."></path>
    </svg>
  </span>
<...>
```

I need to replace the given svg-element with my custom SVG-image. It would be perfect to use an existing SVG-file as a source for generating a new svg-element and then appendChild it into the parent span-element. Unfotunatelly I can't figure out how to do that on my own. When I'm trying to import the necessary image from the existing SVG-file and appendChild it into the span-element I encounter the following error:

```
Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'
```

The only JS-solution I've found in moment is to create a function which recreates my SVG-image string by string like so:

```js
const customizeSelectionDropdownSVG = () => {
    const createNewSVG = () => {
      const xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
      const boxWidth = 16;
      const boxHeight = 16;

      const newSVG = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "svg");
      newSVG.setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", `0 0 ${boxWidth} ${boxHeight}`);
      newSVG.setAttributeNS(null, "width", boxWidth);
      newSVG.setAttributeNS(null, "height", boxHeight);
      newSVG.style.display = "block";

      const path = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "path");
      path.setAttributeNS(null, "class", "b");
      path.setAttributeNS(null, "d", "M160.294,147.293l-2.829-2.829a1,1,0,0,0-1.414,1.415L158.173,148l-2.122,2.121a1,1,0,0,0,1.414,1.415l2.829-2.829A1,1,0,0,0,160.294,147.293Z");
      path.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", "translate(-150 -140)");

      newSVG.appendChild(path);
      return newSVG;
    };
    const customizedSelectionDropdownSVG = createNewSVG();

    const selectorValue = "span";
    const svgContainer = document.querySelectorAll(selectorValue);
    const oldSVG = document.querySelectorAll(`${selectorValue} svg`);

    if (oldSVG && svgContainer) {
      for (let i = 0; i < oldSVG.length; i++) {
        oldSVG[i].remove();
      }
      for (let j = 0; j < svgContainer.length; j++) {
        svgContainer[j].appendChild(customizedSelectionDropdownSVG);
      }
    }
  };
```

And yeah, it works! But looks verbose. So I'm wondering if there is more optimal solution?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> would be perfect to use an **existing SVG-file** as a source for generating a new svg-element

- create a *vanilla* W3C standard Web Component `<load-svg>`
- Load SVG `src` as text
- set it as the `<load-svg>` **innerHTML**

```html
<load-svg src="https://load-file.github.io/heart.svg"></load-svg>

<script>
customElements.define("load-svg", class extends HTMLElement {
  async connectedCallback(  src = this.getAttribute("src")  ) {
    this.innerHTML = await (await fetch( src )).text()
  }
})
</script>

<style>
  svg { height: 180px } /* fit in SO snippet window */
</style>
```

- If you need to load other content, call:

```
document.querySelector("load-svg")
        .connectedCallback("https://load-file.github.io/heart.svg")
```

##### Documentation and more advanced usage:

https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd

Comment: Thank you Danny! Though your solution looks great, I haven't succeeded yet with the implementation. FIrstly, I've created a new class and registered it as a customElement:
`class CustomSVGIcon extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  async connectedCallback(src = this.getAttribute("src")) {
    this.innerHTML = await (await fetch(src)).text();
  }
}
customElements.define("custom-svg", CustomSVGIcon);
`
While trying to use it like `svgContainer.appendChild(<custom-svg src={Images.SELECT_ARROW} />);` I still get the same error _Failed to execute 'appendChild'..._

Comment: Then ``svgContainer`` is **not** a DOM Element. Note: you don't need the bloated ``CustomSVGIcon`` notation. The above used notation does exactly the same.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right @Danny. It works. Replacing `svgContainer.appendChild` with `svgContainer.innerHTML` resolves the case. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the original svg element by setting the innerHTML to an empty string.

```js
const xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
const boxWidth = 16;
const boxHeight = 16;

const newSVG = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "svg");
newSVG.setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", `0 0 ${boxWidth} ${boxHeight}`);
newSVG.setAttributeNS(null, "width", boxWidth);
newSVG.setAttributeNS(null, "height", boxHeight);
newSVG.style.display = "block";

const path = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "path");
path.setAttributeNS(null, "class", "b");
path.setAttributeNS(null, "d", "M160.294,147.293l-2.829-2.829a1,1,0,0,0-1.414,1.415L158.173,148l-2.122,2.121a1,1,0,0,0,1.414,1.415l2.829-2.829A1,1,0,0,0,160.294,147.293Z");
path.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", "translate(-150 -140)");

newSVG.appendChild(path);

document.getElementById('span01').innerHTML = '';
document.getElementById('span01').appendChild(newSVG);
```

```html
<span id="span01">
  <svg></svg>
</span>
```