# How to load an External SVG into Vue as an Object

Tags: vue.js, svg

I need to load an SVG file into a Vue template.  It must be loaded in such a way that I can access the internal classes with js and css, so presumably I'm looking for an `<object>` tag and not an `<img>` tag.

The SVG is located on an external server, not a part of my project.  Vue-Svg-Loader works just fine if I have the svg as part of my project, but doesn't seem to work when the SVG isn't available until runtime.

I've tried the following

```html
<template>
    <div ref="floorplan" id="floorplan-frame">
        <object
            type="image/svg+xml"
            id="floorplan"
            :data="svgPath"
        ></object>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            svgPath: 'http://test-mc4/floorplan.svg',
        };
    },
};
</script>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work.  If I replace the `<object>` tag with `<img :src="svgPath" />` it does show the SVG, but as a static image where the internal css classes are not available.  It does show me that my path is correct and the file is actually available, but it doesn't explain why the object tag is just empty when I use it.

I've searched extensively and I can figure out how to load it as an Object if it's internal, or how to load it External as long as it's an image.  I just can't seem to figure out how to do both.

Comment: Duplicate: [Is it possible to create a DOM node (and then appendChild it into some DOM element) from an existing SVG file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67836374/is-it-possible-to-create-a-dom-node-and-then-appendchild-it-into-some-dom-eleme)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to access the elements within an `<object>`, you'd need to wait until it was loaded (`load` event) and then access the child SVG document by its [`contentDocument` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLObjectElement/contentDocument).

Unfortunately, this won't work in your case because the SVG files are coming from a different origin. The [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) will block access to the `contentDocument`. Here is an example, which also fails (logs `null`) because a `data:` URL is a different origin:

```js
const svgPath = 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiIHN0YW5kYWxvbmU9Im5vIj8+DQo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDIwIDIwIj4NCiAgICA8Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSIxMCIgY3k9IjEwIiByPSIxMCIgZmlsbD0icmVkIi8+DQo8L3N2Zz4=';

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    svgPath,
  },
  methods: {
    svgLoaded() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(this.$refs.object.contentDocument);
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <object
    ref="object"
    :data="svgPath"
    width="100"
    height="100"
    v-on:load="svgLoaded"
  ></object>
</div>
```

The only way to load an SVG from a different origin and then access its internal structure with your JS and CSS would be to `fetch` it and then load it into your component as `v-html`. **Note that this opens significant XSS vulnerabilities**; you should be wary of this option and only use it with external servers you trust. In any case, here's a working example:

```js
const svgPath = 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiIHN0YW5kYWxvbmU9Im5vIj8+DQo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDIwIDIwIj4NCiAgICA8Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSIxMCIgY3k9IjEwIiByPSIxMCIgZmlsbD0icmVkIi8+DQo8L3N2Zz4=';

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    svgData: '',
  },
  async mounted() {
    const svgResponse = await fetch(svgPath);
    this.svgData = await svgResponse.text();
    await Vue.nextTick();

    // SVG is present in the DOM at this point
    const svg = this.$refs.drawing.firstElementChild;
    console.log(svg.outerHTML);

    // DOM manipulations can be performed
    const circle = svg.querySelector('circle');
    circle.setAttribute('fill', 'blue');
    circle.setAttribute('r', '6');
  }
});
```

```css
.drawing {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

/* SVG can be styled as part of the main document */
.drawing circle {
  stroke: cyan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div
    class="drawing"
    ref="drawing"
    v-html="svgData"
  ></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is excellent thank you very much.  It has me so close to where I want to be.  The SVG loads and I can see it as part of my page.  I have two issues remaining.

1) How do I tell when the SVG is done being inserted into the DOM so I can do a querySelectorAll for the classes I'm looking for?  If I do it right after the code you inserted, it just  come back null.  It works if I do a SetTimeout and check again a second later but that's very inelegant.

Comment: 2) The image gets inserted, but my CSS class styles get overwritten by the internal styles on the image itself.  When I inserted the image with vue-svg-loader, I could add a fill: #333333 css style to the image.  Now I do that, but if I look in dev tools I can see that the style inside the SVG is the final one being paid attention to by the browser.  I guess because the SVG gets loaded absolutely last it gets precedent?  Do I just have to use !important on everything?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm actually in complete control of both servers (and in some cases it'll actually be the same server), so I'm not *super* worried about the security issues you mention.  This is for an internal project that will get loaded on a server in each facility.  Everything will be the same everywhere except the floorplan, so I want a single compiled program that gets loaded everywhere that just imports the local floorplan.

Comment: @JeffMcAleer (1) In my example, the point where the SVG is present in the DOM is after `await`ing the `Vue.nextTick` call in the `mounted` handler. You can trigger any DOM-manipulating code from there. (2) Since the SVG is being injected directly into the main document's tree, there is nothing special about it for style precedence. If its internal styles are taking precedence, it's just for the usual reasons. You'll only need `!important` if you can't adjust around those. I've edited the example to show DOM manipulation and external CSS styling of the SVG once it's loaded.

Comment: Interesting.  After `Vue.nextTick` I see that outHTML console log just fine, but my querySelectorAll still returns null.  If I put the same querySelectorAll inside a setTimeout of 1000, it returns what I'm looking for.

Regardless I think you have unlocked the key for what I need to figure out my specific implementation.  I didn't know about v-html, and that seems excellent.  I may try to just load the svg into my Vuex store before this component ever mounts, and that may solve some of my timing issues.  Thanks so much, this is very helpful.